# noun + that + prepositional phrase

Tags: demonstrative

The rap song "[Shook Ones, Part II](https://www.google.com/search?q=mobb%20deep%20-%20shook%20ones%20pt%20ii%20lyrics&newwindow=1&rlz=1C1CHBD_ruRU904RU904&sxsrf=ALiCzsZZDgyxeP0aC7X38QBdmneIiiqpjQ%3A1672379844950&ei=xH2uY9bUOfKGrwSiwqWQDw&ved=0ahUKEwjWxtm01KD8AhVyw4sKHSJhCfIQ4dUDCA8&oq=mobb%20deep%20-%20shook%20ones%20pt%20ii%20lyrics&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQDDIKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzIKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzIKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzIKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzIKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzIKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzIKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzIKCAAQRxDWBBCwA0oECEEYAEoECEYYAFAAWABgng5oAXABeACAAQCIAQCSAQCYAQDIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)" by the group "Mobb Deep":
*Living **the life that of** diamonds and guns*
*There's numerous ways you can choose to earn funds*

Am I right that "*that*" refers to "*the life*"?

Am I right that (1) = (2)?:
**(1)** *living the life that of diamonds and guns*
**(2)** *living the life that **is** of diamonds and guns*

---

To make sure I've understood it, I'll try making up my own sentences with "noun + that + prepositional phrase":

**(3)**:
-*What do I need to take*?
-*You need to take **everything that of prime necessity***.

Is using "*everything that of prime necessity*" in (3) correct?
If not, then why not?

---

**(4)**:
on the phone:
-*I'm in your room now. Which of the books are you talking about*?
-*I'm talking about **the book that on the table***.

Is using "*the book that on the table*" in (4) correct?
If not, then why not?

Comment: Don't treat a song like that as an example of English grammar. They probably inserted the word _that_ just to make the line scan. There is nothing for you to understand or try to copy.

Comment: @KateBunting Is "_the life that of diamonds and guns_" ungrammatical?

Comment: It doesn't make sense.